# Design Patterns - Linking an Enum to an instance of a class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, enums

I have a class that controls how files will be named thoughout my application. It includes things like:

```
public class Filenaming
{
  public string Path{get;}
  public string Extension{get;}
  public int Identifier{get;}
  public int SequenceNumber{get;}
  //etc
}
```

There are two instances of this class in my application. A `DVEncoder` type can hold one or the other, and will name its file according to the instance it uses.

I have decided to use an `enum` to allow the user to switch between the two instances of `Filenaming`. My question is how is the best way to store these two instances, so that the `DVEncoder`, when it switches modes, can then pull the correct instance of `Filenaming`. Should i use a static class, or a Singleton pattern with two `Filenaming` Properties inside, or a Factory pattern?

It kind of "smells" to pass these two insances throughout multiple classes in my app, and then have a `CurrentFilenaming` property to hold the current one. Or maybe this (dependency injection) is the way to go?

Comment: Can the behavior of naming change at runtime?

Comment: Yes they are set by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have exactly 2 instances on the Filenaming class then I suggest you use a singleton + factory.

```
enum FileNamingOptions
{
    Naming1,
    Naming2
}

class FileNamingFactory
{
    // Initialize the first and second instances (maybe in a static contructor)
    private static Filenaming FileNaming1;
    private static Filenaming FileNaming2;

    public static Filenaming GetFileNaming(FileNamingOptions fileNaming)
    {
        if (fileNaming == FileNamingOptions.Naming1)
        {
            return FileNaming1;
        }
        else if (fileNaming == FileNamingOptions.Naming2)
        {
            return FileNaming2;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Your DVEncode can then have one property the will use GetFileNaming method to determine which naming to use.

```
Filenaming CurrentNaming(FileNamingOptions currentOption)
{
    return FileNamingFactory.GetFileNaming(currentOption);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called a [Strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).

> My question is how is the best way to store these two instances, so
>   that the DVEncoder, when it switches modes, can then pull the correct
>   instance of Filenaming

Rather than `DVEncoder` pulling the type it requires, I would suggest you to push the changed `FileNaming` strategy using setter injection.

//Java Code - in place of `int` for id of strategy you can use `enum` of C# I guess

```
class DVEncoder{
   private FileNaming fileNamingStrategy; 
   public void setFileNamingStrategy(FileNaming fileNaming){
     this.fileNamingStrategy = fileNaming;
   }
}

//This is how some other class will change the file naming strategy of DVEncoder
dvEncoderInstance.setFileNamingStrategy(factory.getStrategy(nameOrIdOfStrategy));
```

Now it becomes the responsibility of the object that keeps the `DVEncoder` to inject the proper file naming strategy and `DVEncoder` does not have to lookup in some global space to find the strategy. So you get neat decoupled code, which will also be testable. Testable because you can even pass some `TestFileNamingStrategy` to `DVEncoder` while unit testing.

Seems like I have just removed coupling from `DVEncoder` and the question still remains the same. But to answer that I need to know how is `DVEncoder` notified to change in behavior.

I have used `factory` to get the strategy. My factory code is somewhat different than of @sh_kamalh

```
class FileNamingStrategyFactory{
   public FileNaming getStrategy(int namingID){ //you can use enum here for strategyId
        //constructs a new strategy based on ID
   }
}
```

Now the choice of how factory constructs the strategy depends on whether the strategy classes themselves hold some state. If they don't hold any state then you can use FlyWeight Pattern and return one time generated strategies as in factory example by @sh_kamalh
Otherwise you can generate a new strategy every time when someone asks for it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it's an exact fit for a strategy pattern, I'm not interchanging different implementations, rather the same class, but some useful info here.

Comment: Well IMO you are interchanging different implementations of `FileNaming`. Seems like it should fit.